# Arduino serial communications issue

Tags: arduino

I'm new to Arduino. I'm having some problems connnecting two Arduino's together via an [RF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) module. Everything looks correct to me, but the receiver isn't outputting any text sent from the transmitter. I've also tried connecting pins 10 together directly to both Arduino nano's and again, nothing received on the receiver.

How can this problem be fixed?

```
// ARDUINO NANO TRANSMITTER
#include <VirtualWire.h>
int i;
void setup() {
    vw_set_ptt_inverted(true);
    vw_setup(2000);
    vw_set_tx_pin(10);
}

void loop() {
    const char *msg = "Test Message";
    digitalWrite(13, true);
    vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
    vw_wait_tx();
    digitalWrite(13, false);
    delay(200);
}

// ARDUINO NANO RECEIVER
#include <VirtualWire.h>
int i;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    vw_set_ptt_inverted(true);
    vw_setup(2000);
    vw_set_rx_pin(10);
    vw_rx_start();
}

void loop(){
    uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
    if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)) {
        Serial.println("Found Something:");
        for (i = 0; i < buflen; i++) {
            Serial.print(buf[i]);
        }
        Serial.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: haven't done RF with arduino, but found this tutorial: http://letsmakerobots.com/node/12336 ...I don't fully understand everything, but cold you try to add the #undefs after doing the #include ? (#undef int
#undef abs
#undef double
#undef float
#undef round ). Also double check pins are setup correctly.

Comment: I saw that article too and tried the undef's as well, I have a feeling the issue is with the rf transceivers.

Comment: I would get it working first with a direct connection first. Until this is working, the RF module cannot be made to work.

Comment: What model of transceivers are you using?

Comment: Have you found any solution to your problems? I am still facing them

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the transmitters, you may have to do some tuning.  I had a couple of RF modules that had potentiometers that I could adjust with a small screwdriver.  Another issue I had was not sending enough data quickly enough - sending a single character failed, but sending a whole string worked fine.  This does not appear to be the problem in your case, however.